# Excel Sheet SQL Table

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2005

I have an Excel sheet. The top row corresponds to column names while successive rows each represent an entry.

How can I convert this Excel sheet into a SQL Table?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: this depends/differs on the database you are using

Comment: you could use a vb script to create the necessary sql insert statement. shouldn't be too stressful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on which program you use for SQL . If you have SQL-Server installed. SSIS Import and Export Wizard [SSIS Import and Export Wizard](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm#import_export)  would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use MS Access

Create a new MDB

Import the Excel file as a new table

Use the SQL Server upsizing wizard to transfer the table to SQL Server